# Persisting data in Webmatrix

Tags: razor, persistence, webmatrix

i need some advice on what method i should use when persisting data on my site.

Each member of the site as a property with information about that property spread across multiple tabs (separate pages). I need to know how i can persist the property ID when browsing between these pages, so that they can navigate to a separate tab and still see information about the same property.

I know how to do this using cookies, but am worried that if a user uses a PC where cookies are disabled, this will screw up how things work.

Maybe session variables?

Thanks, Gavin

Answer (score 2):

There are many options for persisting data between requests in ASP.NET Web Pages including

- Hidden Form Fields
- Query Strings
- UrlData
- Cookies
- Session Variables
- Application Variables
- Cache

They differ in their suitability so you should understand how they work before choosing the best one for your scenario.

As a starting point, this article explains the differences: [Transferring Data Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/192/Transferring-Data-Between-ASP.NET-Web-Pages)

Comment: thanks mike, i have read through this (and actually consider your site a holy grail), but i just wanted some clarification on which of your options was best to use for my particular scenario. Once i've confirmed that, i'll use your page to actually implement my findings. Your suggestion would be hugely appreciated. I'm guessing session variables would be best correct?

Comment: Sessions rely on cookies - unless you explicitly implement cookieless state management. If you are clicking links to get from one tab to the next, I would recommend POST requests and a hidden form field.

Comment: Thanks Mike, i'll use your link and see if i can figure out how to implement this. appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Actually Mike, one last question. Is this way of transferring data secure if combined with SSL?

Comment: Yes - the data will be encrypted when the page is posted.

Comment: @Gavin5511 Word of advice when using Session variables: Don't let the page idle (that's probably not a proper term at all, but I think you'll understand what I mean) between when you set the Session variable and when you reference it. If I use Session variables anymore, these days (yes, I've learned my lesson the hard way in the past), I make sure I set it, then use it right away (even if it is only used to plot a hidden field on another page to retain the data). Just thought I'd add to how careful you should be when considering Session variables. They can cause you to redo your whole site...